# Angularjs transform array from input checkbox

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, checkbox

I have multiple input `checkbox`s created from a `model` with angular using `ng-repeat`, when I select some of them I get this:

```
var accounts = [AA764: true, AA324: true, AA234: false, AA553: true, AA7365: false];
```

But I need following structure to manipulate in controller that calls and REST API:

```
var accounts = ['AA764', 'AA324', 'AA553'];
```

This is the way I obtain the array to be converted:

```
<span><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="deleteAsobancariaAccountModalDialog(asobancariaAccounts)"><i class="pe-7s-trash"></i> Eliminar</a></span>

<tbody ng-repeat="account in reconcileBankAccounts">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="asobancariaAccounts[account.accountBankId]"> {{account.accountName}}</td>
        <td>{{account.paymentMethodMain}}</td>
        <td><i class="pe-7s-pen"></i> <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="updateAsobancariaAccountModalDialog(account)">Editar</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the Controller:

```
$scope.deleteAsobancariaAccountModalDialog = function (asobancariaAccounts) {

    console.log(asobancariaAccounts);  // [AA764: true, AA324: true, 'AA234': false, 'AA553': true, 'AA7365': false]

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: SECURE_CONSTANTS.VIEWS + SECURE_CONSTANTS.MODALS.DELETE_ASOBANCARIA_ACCOUNTS,
        size: 'md',
        keyboard: true,
        controller: 'asobancariaCreateController',
        scope: $scope,
        resolve: {
            asobancariaAccount: function(){
                asobancariaAccounts.action = "delete";
                return asobancariaAccounts;
            }                
        }
    });
};
```

Just those `checkbox` that are selected, I have tried with the javascript `foreach` function but I cannot make it work. Is there any library for angular or maybe with bower that can help me? Thanks.

Comment: `var accounts = [AA764: true, AA324: true, AA234: false, AA553: true, AA7365: false];` is an invalid data structure - looks like it should be an array of objects.

Comment: @tymeJV Yes, but it is the way I get it from `ng-model="asobancariaAccounts[account.accountBankId]"` maybe theres another way to set those values to get a correct data structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ng-true-value`.

Read more information in: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D